# what to do in .htaccess file for redirect in login page when user directly access child folders without having login

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have added Options: Indexes in .htaccess file, which is in the root directory. whenever i write path of child folders it says 'You have no permision to access this folder'.

for example : status/ (root)
status/pages/ (child folder)

What i have to write in .htaccess file to redirect in the root .
file structure is :

```
  status/
    index.php
    pages/
      dashboard.php
      setting.php
   include/
      header.php
      footer.php
```

index.php is user login page.
I want that whenever user direct access pages folder it should be redirect on index.php page.

Comment: Have you made any attempts to address this yet? Did you try using php? did you attempt any rewrite rules?

Comment: As far as I'm aware you're not able to access session data from within your .htaccess file. So you aren't able to do so. Instead, look at doing it with only PHP.

Comment: While this is technically possible by adding a parameter in the URL, `.htaccess` is not the most appropriate place to do this thing. It's easier and more flexible to do it in `PHP`. Add the check and the redirect to `header.php` (I guess you include it in all pages) and that's it.

Comment: I have placed .htaccess file in the root directory under status folder. @axiac